# Easily create a Ruby on Rails partial from an existing block of markup using vim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vim, macvim

Is there currently a plugin that you ruby on rails developers that are also using macvim/gvim/vim that allows you to take a quick block of code and create a partial from it? I know that TextMate does this, figured someone has ported it by now to vim also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want Tim Pope's rails.vim plugin:

http://rails.vim.tpope.net/

It provides an `:Rextract` command that pulls a range of lines into a partial. Here's a very short demo of it in action:

http://rails.vim.tpope.net/images/rpartial.gif

(The `:Rpartial` command in the demo is an alias for `:Rextract`.)

The plugin provides dozens of other features, too, and many people consider it a must-have for Rails development in Vim.

Answer (score 6):

It works in **vim** with **vim-rails** plugin.

1. Select in **visual mode** code which you need to send to partial
2. Press key `:` and you will see `:'<,'>`
3. Complete command to `:'<,'>Rextract partial_name` where **partial_name** will your partial's file name. You can set folder for partial, for example `:'<,'>Rextract shared/menu`
4. Press `Enter` and enjoy.

Comment: I like this answer better than the accepted answer because it actually gives step-by-step instructions, rather than just a fragile link to an animated demo which could go away. But it would be even better if you linked to the vim-rails plugin (links may be fragile but they're still useful).

Answer (score 1):

[**rails.vim**](http://rails.vim.tpope.net/) can do this. From the [features summary](http://rails.vim.tpope.net/#features):

> `:Rextract` file replaces the desired
>   range (ideally selected in visual line
>   mode) with `render :partial =>  'file'`,
>   which is automatically created with
>   your content. The `@file` instance
>   variable is replaced with the file
>   local variable.